# Distributed tracing in AWS Nodejs Lambda function for dynamodb stream

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb-streams

Need to implement distributed tracing in AWS Lambda function built with NodeJs. This lambda function will execute as part of the dynamodb stream. In dynamodb document, we are storing `X-B3-TraceId` and `X-B3-SpanId`. Is there any way to instruct Lambda function to use these parameters and record the logs to support distributed tracing requirements?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve that, is via initializing the XRay client from within your lambda application and adding annotation to the current segments. A sample pseudo code would look something like below.

```
// Initialize X-ray AWS SDK
var AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk-core')

// Assuming xb3_traceId and xb3_spanId are being retrieved from stream record

// set xray tracing
// custom annotation to find trace by custom traceId.
let segment = AWSXRay.getSegment()
segment.addAnnotation('X-B3-TraceId', record.xb3_traceId)
segment.addAnnotation('X-B3-SpanId', record.xb3_spanId)
```